# I have a plenty of code for this situation, Is there's a possibility to make the code short?

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML code, I want the button that if click it makes Done and Unclickable. But if the other button is clicked, the previous button click is now clickable. I have an JavaScript and the result is good but the only I suggest is to make the code shortest. I think there's a possible like using querySelectorAll then this.add and item.remove but I dont know
I want to make the JS code shortest, because I have 3 button on that situation, what if I add until 15 button so that the code is many as I expected.

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("BTN");
a[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  a[0].value = "Done";
  a[0].style.background = "grey";
  a[0].disable = true;
  a[1].value = "Click Me!";
  a[1].style.background = "blue";
  a[1].disable = false;
  a[2].value = "Click Me!";
  a[2].style.background = "blue";
  a[2].disable = false;
})

a[1].addEventListener("click", function() {
  a[1].value = "Done";
  a[1].style.background = "grey";
  a[1].disable = true;
  a[0].value = "Click Me!";
  a[0].style.background = "blue";
  a[0].disable = false;
  a[2].value = "Click Me!";
  a[2].style.background = "blue";
  a[2].disable = false;
})

a[2].addEventListener("click", function() {
  a[2].value = "Done";
  a[2].style.background = "grey";
  a[2].disable = true;
  a[1].value = "Click Me!";
  a[1].style.background = "blue";
  a[1].disable = false;
  a[0].value = "Click Me!";
  a[0].style.background = "blue";
  a[0].disable = false;
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.BTN {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="BTN" value="Click Me!">
<input type="button" class="BTN" value="Click Me!">
<input type="button" class="BTN" value="Click Me!">
```

Answer (score 0):

The code begs Delegation.

Then you have ONE event handler instead of one per button

Looping and adding event handlers is not recommended, especially not if you have dynamically added buttons

Also this code will not loop every single button to toggle the Done either

```js
const container = document.getElementById("buttonContainer"); // this can be document if no closer container
container.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest(".BTN");
  if (!tgt) return; // not a button
  const prevButton = container.querySelector("[value=Done]"); // previously clicked if any
  if (prevButton) {
    prevButton.value = "Click Me!";
    prevButton.style.background = "blue";
    prevButton.disabled = false;
  }
  tgt.value = "Done";
  tgt.style.background = "grey";
  tgt.disabled = true;
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.BTN {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonContainer">
  <input type="button" class="BTN" value="Click Me!">
  <input type="button" class="BTN" value="Click Me!">
  <input type="button" class="BTN" value="Click Me!">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote neither. Some explanations about it?
I think that the code is short and fully reach the goal expected by Julom Buenmar N. so I reset the vote.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to reach the expected goal but with a loop in the Collection converted to an Array by using `buttons.forEach` and the deletion of the listener for the button that is clicked trough `clickedButton.removeEventListener("click", clickHandler);`.

I also changed the cursor type if the button is clickable or not.

```js
        let buttons = null;
        let collection = null;

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", addElements);

        function addElements() {
            collection = document.getElementsByClassName("BTN");
            buttons = Array.from(collection);
            checkButtons();
        }

        function checkButtons() {
            buttons.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener("click", clickHandler));
        }

        function clickHandler(e) {
            const clickedButton = e.target;
            
            if (clickedButton.value === "Click Me!") {
                const prevClickedButton = buttons.find((button) => button.value === "Done");
                if (prevClickedButton) {
                    prevClickedButton.value = "Click Me!";
                    prevClickedButton.classList.remove("inactive");
                    prevClickedButton.classList.add("active");
                    prevClickedButton.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
                }

                clickedButton.classList.add("inactive");
                clickedButton.value = "Done";
                clickedButton.removeEventListener("click", clickHandler);
            } else {
                clickedButton.classList.remove("inactive");
                clickedButton.classList.add("active");
                clickedButton.value = "Click Me!";
            }
        }
```

```css
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .BTN {
            background: blue;
            color: white;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 5px;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .active {
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
        }

        .inactive {
            background-color: gray;
            color: white;
            cursor: default;
        }
```

```html
    <input type="button" class="BTN" value="Click Me!">
    <input type="button" class="BTN" value="Click Me!">
    <input type="button" class="BTN" value="Click Me!">
    <input type="button" class="BTN" value="Click Me!">
    <input type="button" class="BTN" value="Click Me!">
```